# Assembly IA32: Move 4 byte float from stack to FPU

Tags: floating-point, fpu, x86

At my university we are introduced to IA32/x86 assembler with AT&T Syntax. But the explanation lacks of important information.

How am I able to move a 4 byte float from the stack to the FPU? I tried with flds but it didn't work as expected...

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
.data
        fl:     .float 12.412
        test:   .string "Result: %f\n"

.text
.global main

main:
        # Prepare the stack (8 byte so i can use it for printf later)
        subl $8, %esp
        # Load the variable fl which holds 12.412
        fld fl
        # Store the previously loaded value as single precision (4 byte) to the stack
        fstps (%esp)
        # Load the value from the stack again and expect it to be single precision (as flds ends with s)
        flds (%esp)


        # Push it to the stack again. But this time as double precision value als printf expects floats to be 8 bytes long 
        fstp (%esp)
        pushl $test
        call printf

        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

But the output is:

**Result: -0.491594**

and not 12.412 as expected...

**[EDIT:] Funny fact. Surprisingly the result changes for every single execution of the program.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that (right before you call `printf`) you use the wrong instruction to pop the FPU's top onto the stack. Your comment says "...this time as double precision...", but what you actually do with `fstp` is storing a single-precision value. Try `fstpl` and it will store a double-precision value.

The fixed code should look something like this:

```
.data
        fl:     .float 12.412
        test:   .string "Result: %f\n"

.text
.global main

main:
        subl $8, %esp
        fld fl
        fstps (%esp)
        flds (%esp)

        fstpl (%esp)        # This line is the only one that has been changed.
        pushl $test
        call printf

        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```